# npm install bcrypt

Tags: python, windows, node.js, heroku, npm

Locally, when I do:

```
npm install bcrypt
```

I get:

> ImportError no module named site

But when I deploy to heroku, it installs just fine. What might be my issue? I tried a few configurations, I have python 2.7 and node 0.8.17

Comment: Do you have each of [bcrypt's dependencies](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js#dependencies) installed, including [`node-gyp`'s own dependencies](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/#installation)?

Comment: It's a Python error. You need Python 2.x to install bcrypt.

Comment: [`site` module is in Python stdlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html). Does `python -m site` produce the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install `bcrypt` you shall meet all [dependencies](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/#dependencies).

You also need a stable version of node:

> node-gyp only works with stable/released versions of node. Since the
>   bcrypt module uses node-gyp to build and install you'll need a stable
>   version of node to use bcrypt.

For windows users there is an additional requirment:

> Windows users should make sure to have at least node 0.8.5 installed
>   and version >= 0.7.1 of this module.

Your error looks like Python error. Installing Python 2.x should help. `site` is in Python stdlib, so it should be always present.

If you already have Python installed, make sure its version is 2.x.

Comment: neat, I had python installed but it was an incompatible version, I had tried 3.3 too, but it said it was incompatible (diff. message) and I fell back to my existing one. 2.7 did the trick.

Comment: `site` is in Python stdlib. It should be always present.